# I want to know if my server was shutdown and time that is shutting down in

Tags: ubuntu-server

i have a server hp with ubuntu server 
 I want to know if my server was shutdown and time that is shutting down in
 there are something to know a logs of my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `last reboot` command to get some basic information about the most recent reboots and the uptime between them.

```
# last reboot
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-431.3.1.e Fri Mar 14 07:02 - 01:51 (8+18:49)   
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-431.3.1.e Sun Feb 16 02:15 - 06:59 (26+03:44)  
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-431.3.1.e Sun Jan 26 16:21 - 06:59 (46+13:38)  
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Sun Oct 13 18:53 - 16:18 (104+22:25) 
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Sun Oct  6 10:10 - 18:50 (7+08:40)   
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Sat Jun 29 09:28 - 10:06 (99+00:38)  
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.11.1. Sat Jun 29 09:06 - 09:25  (00:19)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-358.6.2.e Sat Jun 29 08:46 - 09:01  (00:15)
```